# Dynamically changing columns sizes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have three columns on my page, but column2 should initially have a size of column size of 0, ie `col-md-0`. When the user clicks on a link in the navigation bar, I would like column2 to expand to `col-md-3`, and column3 should shrink to adjust.

For example, this is what I would imagine my columns' `html` to be when the page is loaded:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div id="col1" class="col-md-1">
            <vs-navbar></vs-navbar>
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-0">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div id="col3" class="col-md-11">
            <div class="placeholder">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `navbar` could be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-full">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li>
            <a>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When the `Info` link is clicked, I would like the `html` to transition to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div id="col1" class="col-md-1">
            <vs-navbar></vs-navbar>
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-3">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div id="col3" class="col-md-8">
            <div class="placeholder">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a vague but messy idea how this could be done with some javascript, but I've seen this kind of thing on several sites so I'm looking for the clean, recommended way of doing this, especially as I'm using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have IDs, I assume you now the exact structure of your row.

If it is so, a solution can be based on **toggleClass**:

```js
$('a:contains("Info")').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#col2').toggleClass('col-md-0 col-md-3')
  $('#col3').toggleClass('col-md-11 col-md-8')
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-full">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li>
            <a>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Info</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div id="col1" class="col-md-1">
            <vs-navbar>aaaaaa</vs-navbar>
        </div>
        <div id="col2" class="col-md-0">
            <router-outlet>bbbbbb</router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div id="col3" class="col-md-11">
            <div class="placeholder">cccc
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:target` pseudo-class for this.

> The :target pseudo-class is used to style an element that is the
>   target of an internal link in a document.

Basically you hide your column, then when the user clicks the link it will show up:

```
#col2{
  display: none;
}

#col2:target{
  display: block;
}
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  height: 100px;
}
.col:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: gold;
}
#col2 {
  display: none;
  animation: open 300ms linear both;
}
#col2:target {
  display: block;
}
@keyframes open {
  0 {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#col2">Trigger Col 2</a>
<div class="row">
  <div id="col1" class="col"></div>
  <div id="col2" class="col"></div>
  <div id="col3" class="col"></div>
</div>
```

---

### EDIT:

To change between `.col-md-8` and `.col-md-11`, you can change the width of `.col-md-8`when your second column is not present, using the corresponding media query for md viewport.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #col2 + .col-md-8 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  #col2:target + .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
}
```

Bootstrap demo:

```css
div[class*="col"],
div[class^="col"] {
  height: 100px;
}
#col1 {
  background-color: gold;
}
#col3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
#col2 {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: none;
  animation: open 300ms linear both;
}
#col2:target {
  display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #col2 + .col-md-8 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  #col2:target + .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
}
@keyframes open {
  0 {
    transform: rotateX(0);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href="#col2">Trigger Col 2</a>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row no-gutter">
    <div id="col1" class="col-md-1">
      <vs-navbar></vs-navbar>
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col-md-3">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="col-md-8">
      <div class="placeholder">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a neat idea, but then it wouldn't change the `col-md-x` which is necessary for bootstrap to display the columns properly.

Comment: There will be no need to change between col-md-x. Just set it normally to col-md-3, but hide it. You can use an utility class there.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that you wanted your column to change from 8 to 11. I only noticed on the first one. You can fix this as well with a media query since bootstrap just changed width between cols.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you this can be achieved with pure CSS. Cheers.

Comment: I will give this a try and get back to you!